# The given key was not present in the dictionary IIS

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2013, query-string

I'm trying to figure out whats going on here. I have Web App "A" which has a link to Web App "B". Web App "B" expects a query string "id". When I navigate from Web App "A" to Web App "B" in localhost, the page loads with no issue.

Now, when I navigate from Web App "A" to Web App "B" through the IIS I get error:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Anyone has an idea what might be going on here?

Comment: How are you "navigating"? Are you using an `<a>` tag? If so, what url is assigned to the href?

Comment: I redirect the user in code-behind like this: Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientExperienceUrl"] + e.CommandArgument.ToString()); I read the link from the web.config